# Overwrite render method extending from parentComponent in lit element

Tags: web-component, extend, lit-element

im trying to create a new lit element component extending from other component
but render method don´t works.
the component is empty..

```
export default class ChildComponent extends FatherComponent {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      :host {
        display: block;
      }`;
  }

  render() {
    return html`<h1>Hi</h1>`;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('child-component', ChildComponent);
```

Comment: Your `ChildComponent` works fine so it's an issue with the parent component. What does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of issue today. It seems that render() was not triggered.

To solve my issue I had to call super.connectedCallback() in the connectedCallback() methods for both child and parent.

I also call super() in the constructor.

Hope that helps.